# Repartion multiple disks and reallocate storage

Tags: partition, disk

I’m trying to re-partition from an Arch Linux install disc. I’m doing so because my current OS is corrupted.

When running `fdisk –l` this is what it looks like:

```
/dev/sda1 * start=2048 end=1026047 blocks=512000 id=83 system=linux     
/dev/sda2   start=10264048 end=625141759 blocks=312057856 id=8e system=linux LVM
```

I need to wipe everything clean, partition `/sda1` for 15gb for the OS install, and then partition `/sda2` to have the rest. What is the cleanest and least time consuming  way to accomplish this?

One option I've found to do this is using this type of command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda
```

However, I'm not entirely sure if I should do this to both disks or one, or the other. I'm not entirely sure that would solve my problem and I know it is very time consuming.

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't you just do the following:

1. Boot the Arch Linux install disc.
2. Run `fdisk /dev/sda`.

   ```
   linux-1reo:~ # fdisk /dev/sda
   The number of cylinders for this disk is set to 9729. 
   There is nothing wrong with that, but this is larger than 1024, 
   and could in certain setups cause problems with: 
   1) software that runs at boot time (e.g., old versions of LILO) 
   2) booting and partitioning software from other OSs 
      (e.g., DOS FDISK, OS/2 FDISK) 

   Command (m for help):
   ```
3. Delete the existing partitions using the <kbd>d</kbd> option.
4. Then with all the partitions deleted, create a new one using the <kbd>n</kbd> option. This will be the 1st partition, `/dev/sda1`.

   ```
   Command (m for help): n 
   First cylinder (7921-9729, default 7921): 
   Using default value 7921 
   Last cylinder or +size or +sizeM or +sizeK (7921-9729, default 9729): +15G
   ```
5. Repeat step #4, but this time just go with the default choices.
6. Next double check the partition types are set correctly. They both should be "Linux". For example:

   ```
   Command (m for help): p 

   Disk /dev/sda: 80.0 GB, 80026361856 bytes 
   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9729 cylinders 
   Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes 

      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System 
   /dev/sda1   *           1        1402    11261533+   7  HPFS/NTFS 
   /dev/sda2            1403        1415      104422+  83  Linux 
   /dev/sda3            1416        1546     1052257+  82  Linux swap / Solaris 
   /dev/sda4            1547        9729    65729947+   5  Extended 
   /dev/sda5            1547        7920    51199123+  8e  Linux LVM 
   /dev/sda6            7921        8045     1004031   83  Linux
   ```
7. Once everything is set, then write the changes to disk, using the <kbd>w</kbd> option.

   ```
   Command (m for help): w 
   The partition table has been altered! 

   Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table. 

   WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy. 
   The kernel still uses the old table. 
   The new table will be used at the next reboot. 
   Syncing disks.
   ```
8. Final steps will include formatting the partitions using `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1` and `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda2`.

#### References

- [Manually Partitioning Your Hard Drive with fdisk](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/19350.html)